# How to render video/audio files using Flash Players on html page

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, adobe

I am rendering audio or video files on my html page. I have tried for HTML5 tags but 3gp, 3gpp video or aac, amr audio files are not supported by HTML5. I have tried following code but some how I am not able to get the video playing on my website.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://localhost/images/Sachin.mp4" width="550" height="400" >
              <param name="movie" value="https://localhost/images/Sachin.mp4"/>
          <!--<![endif]-->
              <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                  <!-- <video width="320" height="240" controls src="https://localhost/images/Video12.webm"> </video> -->
                  <img src="https://localhost/images/Video12.webm" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
                   <video id="video" controls>
                     <source src="https://localhost/images/Sachin.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  </video>
              </a>
          <!--[if !IE]>-->
          </object>
```

Comment: `data=` should be a link to your Flash file (**.swf**). You have to use AS3 code to create a custom player and compile as SWF then put that on your web page (the Flash browser plugin will understand and display your SWF file, which you have programmed to load the required media file). Basically you'll have to learn a new programming language (AS3).

Comment: Thanks @VC.One, I am able to see the Image using this code and when I have given the link of .mp4 video then It is not rendering the video, can you tell me how exactly I should use the object of flash player.

Comment: Find a free Flash-based video player (try **videoJS** or **JWPlayer**).  They'll have instructions to embed their SWF file as `<object>` tag etc. Check the supported formats, not everyone writes code for AAC or AMR playback in Flash. Or you can use a `<video>` tag to show MP4 / webM / OGV files (as shown by @rolu) via HTML5. That image source is simply for an image advising that "you need Flash installed" or video poster etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the source element? If you want to support Modern browsers, I would suggest using webm but for IE, you'll have to install the webm component.

E.G.

```
<video controls>
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rolu, I have already used this but not working. Please can you tell me how exactly I should use the flash player object.